# Error when suspending MSI 65 Stealth, Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: suspend, msi

When I suspend my laptop and turn it back on it looses wireless connectivity and its unable to recognized my external monitor,

When I reboot the computer the wireless connection goes back on but to get the monitor working I have to go the bios and enable and disable the secure boot for it to start working,

any ideas why this problem might be showing up?

Computer MSI Stealth 65
Dual Boot = Main Windows 10, secondary Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Just keep Secure Boot disabled.

Comment: Hi, I normally have Secure Boot disable but the error persists. 

Usually I have to go back and forward with enabling and disabling Secure Boot to solve the problem, although I don't think that is an optimal solution

Comment: For any dual-boot with Windows disabling the Windows Fast Startup feature (and shutdown) is a must. Keep Secure Boot disable and try again after having Windows booting without the fake fast startup which is semi-hibernation and often has the effect of not allowing proper hardware initialization when rebooted to another OS.